# Cannot locate Firefox Helper Location

Tags: startup-applications

I want to use specific applications to open files in Firefox.  Where do I direct the Helper Application preference to to find that application?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Applications`. Find your file and assign what application you want to it.

[image]